# Shade areas under the stacked area in Excel

Tags: excel

[image]

I want to be able to shade certain areas of the graph, where the graph is based on this data [enter link description here](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=e76aa0e85f739590f112941527bfc72d4ab3564e6bb51d4ab7a65b0a09301c98f27a8f6fdf771841bb87d752823c1b1303ae0f2cc6820eefb0a11d503bbcb099)

Specifically, I want to be able to point out some interesting periods for certain sectors (e.g. 2000-2000 in Information Tech, 2008-2011 in Financials, 2011-2014 in Energy) by shading the areas and write little notes like (IT bubble, Financials Crisis, etc.) for each of them. How do I achieve this in excel?

The output should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you essentially "duplicate" the data for those periods, and have it create another color?

Comment: @BruceWayne Hmm.. how do I do that?